# Is it true that if $\int f \,\text{d}\mu <\infty$ then $f$ is bounded almost everywhere?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space, $f:X\to [0,\infty)$ a measurable function, and suppose that $\int f<\infty$. I have the feeling that this must imply that $f$ is bounded almost everywhere, i.e., that there exists $M\in\mathbb R$ such that $\mu(\{x\in X\,:\,f(x)> M\})=0$. I'm not sure, however, and have not yet succeeded at proving it, nor found a proof somewhere else.

Could anyone give a proof of this statement or help me out of my dream (and preferably give a counterexample)?

Comment: One can construct a function $f$ for which $\mu( \{ x\in X:f(x)>n \})=\frac{1}{n^3} $ (in $X=\mathbb{R}$ I would draw stairs at height $n$ and measuring $\frac{1}{n^3}$ by side). In this way $\int f <\sum \frac{1}{n^2}<+\infty$, and $f$ is not bounded everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at $X=(0,1]$ and $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$.

Comment: I drawed this function on the plane $(x,y=f(x))$, the converging integral can be written also $\int_{-\infty}^1\frac{1}{{y}^2}$, whose convergence is equivalent to that of the series $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ I gave in my comment. :)